# How to extract data from formatted string using python?

Tags: python, regex, string, text, string-formatting

I have a set of strings like this:

> C001F01.PNG
>
> C001G01.PNG
>
> C002F10.PNG

which follow the format of :

> C(id number)(F or G)(another id number).PNG

I want to know their ids' and know if they were from class F or G, I have read that `re.split()` could do similar work, but I'm confused and don't understand how RE works exactly.

Comment: See [What does the regex mean](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean) for a ton of nice hints on that.

Comment: [Learning Regular Expressions](//stackoverflow.com/q/4736)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should certainly read more on regex. A first hint is that when you want to capture a pattern you need to enclose it in parentheses. e.g. (\d+). For this example though, the code you need is:

```
match = re.match(r'C(\d+)([F|G])(\d+)\.PNG', s)

first_id = match.group(1)
fg_class = match.group(2)
second_id = match.group(3)
```

Comment: thanks a lot. I've tried to read this(https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html), but couldn't understand it much.

Answer (score 0):

```
s = "123STRINGabcabc"

def find_between( s, first, last ):
    try:
        start = s.index( first ) + len( first )
        end = s.index( last, start )
        return s[start:end]
    except ValueError:
        return ""



print find_between( s, "123", "abc" )
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please see [How do I format my code blocks?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186)